# Mobile phone, share image still in buffer

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-pwa

On mobile phone I want to provide image share using Javascript `navigate.share()` method

This interface requires a list of files for attachment as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share#examples)

In the share files example, the interface requires the user to select a file, however, the image I want to share resides in a buffer (large string).

How can I share that buffer as a file?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your buffer to string by doing

```
var myString = myBuffer.toString();
```

Then converting it to blob

```
var blob = new Blob([myString], { type: 'text/plain' });
```

And finally to file

```
var file = new File([blob], "myFile.jpg", {type: "image/jpeg"});
```